# Custom Hosts file entry resolves in browser but not when pinged

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, hosts-file

I have a hosts entry to redirect `app-dev/` to my application server. This resolves correctly in the browser but when I try to ping `app-dev/` or ssh into it, neither can resolve the name then. The only change I made was to add a line in the /etc/hosts file and flush the dns cache. What am I forgetting? Or is this just not possible outside of the browser?

Comment: to clarify, you are not entering the trailing / when attempting to ping/ssh, right? that would not work correctly.

Comment: Ah. That was stupid. That was the way I was forced to enter it in the browser. This worked. Feel free to post as an answer!